# How to Convert php code in to angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have php code which I want to convert into angular. I have done same thing using php. I want following output using `angularjs`.

This is screenshot of my output.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk6Qt.png][1]][1]

For that I have done php code which is following:

```
<?php

   function buildMenu($parentId, $menuData,$counter)
   {
   $html = '';
   if (isset($menuData['parents'][$parentId]))
   {
    $html = '<ul>';$counter++;
    switch ($counter) {
        case 1:
            $style='#ff7a85';                 
            break;
        case 2:
            $style='#0074a2';            
            break;
        case 3:
            $style='#33B940';
            break;            
       case 4:
            $style='#ffa62f';
            break;                       
    }

    foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId)
           {
            $html .= '<li><p><span style="font-weight:boldfont-size:13px;  padding-left:'.($counter*20).'px;color:'.$style.'">';
            $html .= $menuData['items'][$itemId]['TASK_NAME']."</span></p>";
            $html .= '<p>'.$menuData['items'][$itemId]['TASK_CREATOR_NAME'].'</p>';
            $html .= '<p>'.$menuData['items'][$itemId]['TASK_ESTIMATED_HOURS'].'</p>';
            $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData,$counter);
            $html .= '</li>';

            }
    $html .= '</ul>';
}

return $html;
}

if(!empty($menuData)) {
     $counter=0;
     $test_res =  buildMenu(0, $menuData,$counter);
     $test_res = str_replace("<li>","<tr style='border:1px solid   #ccc'>",$test_res);
     $test_res = str_replace("</li>","</tr>",$test_res);
     $test_res = str_replace("<p>","<td style='border:1px solid #ccc'>",$test_res);
     $test_res = str_replace("</p>","</td>",$test_res);
     $test_res = str_replace("<ul>","",$test_res);
     $test_res = str_replace("</ul>","",$test_res);
```

I want same output using `angularjs` for that I have done some code which is following:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="task in tasks.items">
    <tr ng-if="task.PARENT_TASK_ID==0" ng-bind="task.ID">
       <td><font face="verdana" size="2"><strong>{{task.TASK_NAME}}</strong></font></td>
       <td>{{task.TASK_CREATOR_NAME}}</td>
       <td>{{task.TASK_ESTIMATED_HOURS}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="task.PARENT_TASK_ID!=0">
       <td><font face="verdana" size="2">{{task.TASK_NAME}}</font></td>
       <td>{{task.TASK_CREATOR_NAME}}</td>
       <td>{{task.TASK_ESTIMATED_HOURS}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But I am not getting appropriate output. Please help me in solving this.

Comment: If you want the same output, why are you using `ul`/`li` in php, and `tr`/`td` in your angular templates?

Comment: Using  `php` i have got expected output,but i am new to angular js.I have not completed whole code using `angularjs`.I am stuck from this point.I don't know how to get expected output.